# Single yaml file for multiple azure repos

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-repos

**Background -**
I have multiple web service projects under multiple azure repos. All these projects have same structure as they are ASP.NET core web applications. I have written separate yaml pipelines and created separate yaml jobs for each project which has similar steps and placed them in separate azure repos.

**Issue -**
I have created separate yaml pipeline jobs (multistage - build and deploy) depending on each yaml. Is there any way to consolidate these yaml to one and place to shared azure repo and trigger the pipelines on the code commit to respective azure repos and deploy it to their related environments on azure web services?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to consolidate these yaml to one and place to shared azure repo and trigger the pipelines on the code commit to respective azure repos and deploy it to their related environments on azure web services?

The answer is yes.

You could create a new repo with a new YAML file in it, or you could select one repo as main repo and set the YAML with [Repository resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#repository-resource-definition):

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: A
    type: git
    name: MyProject/A
    ref: main
    trigger:
    - main

  - repository: B
    type: git
    name: MyProject/B
    ref: release
    trigger:
    - main
    - release
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. This looks more generic way. I'll try this scenario on multi-repos.

Comment: @AjitMedhekar, Glad to know that. This is the current solution to repeatedly placing and managing the same YAML file in multiple repos, hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to manage these is a separate repo as template. Essentially your template contains the pipeline steps that you want to run, and for each pipeline you need you have a yaml file that extends the template by defining what triggers you want for that pipeline and pass any pipeline dependant parameters you are using to the template.

[Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Yes, templates option I was trying. But I was looking for more generic way. Thanks for your inputs.